# if(xxx || xxx), what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Can someone explain to me what am I doing wrong?

```
function navMenuIntervalCheck() {
    if (currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php" || currentSiteUrl != "subsites/itemshop.php") {
        $.ajax({
            url: currentSiteUrl,
            cache: false,
            success: function (dataForContainer) {
                $('#container').html(dataForContainer);
            }
        });
    }

    screenControlCheck();
};

setInterval(function () {
    navMenuIntervalCheck()
}, 5000);
```

When I run my website it refreshes even when `currentSiteUrl==subsites/players.php`

Comment: Where do you assign `currentSiteUrl`?

Comment: && vs || ?, the second condition matches

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As `x!='a' || x!='b'` is always `true`, I guess you wanted `&&` instead of `||`.

Read `||` as `OR` and `&&` as `AND`.

More details in [the MDN on logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: I through && means and so currentSiteUrl would have to have both values :/

Answer (score 3):

`currentSiteUrl` can only have one value, so it will always be that at least one of the values you're testing will not equal `currentSiteUrl`, making the `if` condition always `true`.

I think you meant to use `&&` or you meant to do `==` with `||`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code says this :

Refresh when currentSiteUrl is different than subsites/players.php or different than subsites/itemshop.php.

So subsites/players.php is indeed different than subsites/itemshop.php

Use && instead of ||

Answer (score 2):

Look at your if statement:

```
if (a != foo || a != bar)
```

Lets look at the possibilities:

- a = foo.  This will evaluate as true, because a != bar
- a = bar.  This will evaluate as true, because a != foo
- a = anything else.  This will evaluate as true, because a != foo

Your if statement always evaluates to true.

As others have already said, you want to replace your `||` with `&&`.

Let me throw a logical rule at you, called [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  It's really useful when learning how to set up a good `if` statement.

```
!(a || b) === !a && !b
```

also

```
!(a && b) === !a || !b
```

What that says is: "Not (one event or another)" is the same thing as "Not one event and not another", and "Not (one event and another)" is the same thing as "Not one event or not the other".

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered but thought it might help to add some additional information using your own code.

As said, switching [**logical operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) from `||` to `&&` will work:

```
if (currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php" && currentSiteUrl != "subsites/itemshop.php")
```

But why is that?

---

**Using `||`**

---

The `||` logical operator returns `true` if either the first or second expression is `true` and only if both are `false` will it return `false`.

Hence:

- if `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php"` is `true` you end up in the `if` block
- if `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php"` is `false` and `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/itemshop.php"`  is `true` you end up in the `if` block

There will never be another scenario as your variable `currentSiteUrl` can only hold a single value and as such one of the expressions will always be `true` causing you to always end up in the `if` block.

---

**Using `&&`**

---

Using the `&&` logical operator on the other hand though returns `false` if either the first or second expression is `false` and only if both are `true` will it return `true`.

Hence:

- if `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php"` is `true` and `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/itemshop.php"` is `true` you end up in the `if` block
- if `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php"` is `true` and `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/itemshop.php"` is `false` you **don't** end up in the `if` block
- if `currentSiteUrl != "subsites/players.php"` is `false` you **don't** end up in the `if` block

There will never be another scenario, because only if both expression are `true` will you end up in the `if` block and as soon as either expression is `false` will you not.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the currentSiteUrl. A url is followed by protocol:://domain

Try using the follwoing property to get URL and then match it

```
window.location.href
```

This url will also include the http or https and domain name